# How to Kill focus of an MFC button control

Tags: button, mfc, dialog, focus

I have an MFC button control and I am trying to handle the "OnPressed" event of it by starting a timer on click and making it go through my event in the OnTimer function. This all works fine but the focus remains on the button and if I click outside of the button area, the app carries out the OnPressed event. Any suggestions on how to kill the focus on the button when the mouse is pressed outside of the button area? My code for getting the focus and button ID.

```
void Dlg::OnTimer(...)
{
CWnd * pFocus = GetFocus();
int btnID = 0;
if (pFocus != NULL && pDialog->IsChild(pFocus))
    btnID = pFocus->GetDlgCtrlID();

// Carry on my button pressed activity
Buttonpressed();
}
```

So basically I am getting the proper button press and I can carry out the desired action using the Buttonpressed() function given above. Now my problem is, once that button is pressed, it gets focus and the focus remains even after I leave the mouse and move out of the area of the button. Because of this behaviour, if I click outside of the button area, the application still thinks that I am in the mouse area and pressing the button. Is there a way I could remove focus after the mouse is moved out of the button area and then bring focus back in again when it is in the button area?

Looking forward to your suggestions.

Comment: Be more specific and show more code,.

Comment: Your `OnTimer` is equivalent to `void Dlg::OnTimer(...) {}`. Other than that, it is unclear what you are trying to achieve. And why.

Comment: Hello, I have updated my question. Looking forward to your suggestions/